# Implement Do loop with extension function

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I want to know if it's possible to implement a Do Loop with an extension function.

Here's my non-working code:

```vb
  <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
  Public Sub DoUntil(condition As Func(Of Boolean), action As Action)
    Do Until condition
      action()
    Loop
  End Sub
```

So it could be called like:

```
   DoUntil(Function() Finished = True, Sub()
 x = x + 1
If IsPrime(x) Then
  Finished = True
)
```

But I get error: Value of type 'System.Func(Of Boolean)' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use a do-loop for this at all? Why not just a .Count() ?

Comment: Maybe show some code about what you have in mind. I'm not following you how count can do this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it would be best if you first explained what your code is actually trying to achieve. So please expand/edit your question to explain what's going on / what you're trying to achieve. From the looks of it, you'd need something like: `TableAliasCounter =  TableAliases.Values.Count(x => x.StartsWith(PKTableAlias))`. But that is just a quick guess (and StartsWith is probably not *exactly* what you need). Eventually you're probably going to end up using a Count() with a regex like `PKTableAlias[0-9]+`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `do` loop in LINQ. You can often accomplish the same thing that a `do` loop is used for. However, it's unclear what the code you've provided is trying to do. Can you provide some examples of expected input and output from this loop?

Comment: you don't need a do loop with linq, everything you do in linq is essentially looped. What you need to do is set the conditions for a result set, then perform a count at the end of that expression. So like var results = myCollection.Where(i => i.MyProperty == x).Count(); Of course there are plenty of other operators to use, but I don't understand what's happening in the code enough for a better example.

Comment: @Roblll, maybe he could delegate his concatenation in a contains clause? then perform the count.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it using the Ask Question link in the upper right-hand corner of this page.  Don't edit your existing question into a new one.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - but now the ? does not match the accepted answer. My mistake was my previous edit, not this last one. If you undo your edit, the ? will match the answer. As it is ,it's confusing.

Comment: It looks to me like he read your code, assumed you were trying to create a count(), and answered accordingly.  Nothing confusing about that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have this (C#, sorry, I'm not very proficient with VB):

```
//Table name we're looking for
var LookingFor = "Foo";
//Tablenamess returned by some function (in this case some array)
var Foos = new[] { "Bar", "Foobar", "Foo_w00t", "Foo1", "foo7", "SomeFoo", "Foo_3", "Foo4", "F00", "Foo" };
```

Getting the count is easy:

```
//Look for "XXX[0-9]+" where XXX is the (case insensitive for demonstration purposes) tablename
Regex r = new Regex(string.Format("^{0}[0-9]*$", Regex.Escape(LookingFor)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var count = Foos.Count(x => r.IsMatch(x));
```

This returns `4` (`Foo1`, `foo7`, `Foo14` and `Foo`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that if you just need to know de number of registers that satisfy your condition (i've taken this example from the [101 LINQ samples for VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088.aspx))

```
Public Sub Linq74()
Dim numbers() = {5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0}

Dim oddNumbers = numbers.Count(Function(n) n Mod 2 = 1)

Console.WriteLine("There are {0} odd numbers in the list.", oddNumbers)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var myCollection = new List<string> {"Jeremy 1", "Jeremy 2", "Christy 1", "Tyler 1", ""};
    //using a while loop
    var counter = 0;
    var index = 0;
    var testString = myCollection[index];
    while (myCollection[index] != "")
    {
        counter++;
        index++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The count was: " + counter);

    //using linq
    Console.WriteLine("The count was: " + myCollection.Count(i => i != ""));
```

Actually, the first example (bad as it may be) is flawed. It will stop counting as soon as it encounters a false condition. The linq expression will print the count of all elements that are not empty.

Now if you WANTED it to stop counting the instant it encounters a a false condition, then you are talking about sentinel values. In that case, a loop is probably the simplest solution. Generally, I only use linq when I'm working with a collection in the same way that I would in a database. I only extend them (improper use of the word imo) through the use of lambda expressions when I want to perform an immediate action on the "query" results.

Comment: So you DO want it to stop as soon as it encounters a certain condition?

Comment: Ok, so then you're dealing with sentinels. Keep in mind in the future when you're thinking of LINQ that it stands for Language INtegrated Query. Query being the keyword in this case. When you run a query, you are working with the entire set. When dealing with sentinels, you ignore everything that comes after the sentinel value, so it's not a query. Anything convoluted use of extensions would be like strapping a laser to the head of a shark. While it looks impressive, its like "dude, the thing is underwater the whole time, what's the point?"